# Use LINEST on filtered data - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I am trying to use the LINEST function and then filter the original data to reflect the subset I am interested in. Unfortunately LINEST always uses all originally defined data. Is there a way to obtain the data from the filtered data? - the 'trendline' works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a dataset in A2:B10 (with *known_y's* and *known_x's* in A2:A10 and B2:B10 respectively), first go to Name Manager (*Formulas* tab) and define:

*Arry1* as:

=ROW($A$2:$A$10)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$10))

*Arry2* as:

=SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET($A$2,Arry1,,,))

The required **array formula**** is then:

=LINEST(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(Arry2,Arry1+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(Arry2))))))),INDEX($B$2:$B$10,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(Arry2,Arry1+1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM(Arry2))))))))

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*